# An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, asp.net-routing

While I am trying to insert values into the database in `asp.net mvc4` with entity framework, it is throwing an exception. Help me to solve this exception.

The error message is: `An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details`.

This is my code in controller

```
{
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult rated(FormCollection form)
        {
            int ratedvalue = Convert.ToInt32(form["rating"]);
            using (var db = new FSLIndiaLatest.Models.FSLWebEntitiesContext())
            {
                var value = new FSLIndiaLatest.Models.Tbl_Rating();
                value.Rating = Convert.ToInt32(ratedvalue);
                value.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                value.CreatedBy = 2;
                db.Tbl_Rating.Add(value);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return View(form);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell what record are you getting by writing this:
`var value = new FSLIndiaLatest.Models.Tbl_Rating();`

Comment: I am assigning all the table to the object. From that object i am assigning the value for table attributes.